# Is this a viable MapReduce use case or even possible to execute?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, bigdata

I am new to Hadoop, MapReduce, Big Data and am trying to evaluate it's viability for a specific use case that is extremely interesting to the project that I am working on. I am not sure however if what I would like to accomplish is A) possible or B) recommended with the MapReduce model.

We essentially have a significant volume of widgets (known structure of data) and pricing models (codified in JAR files) and what we want to be able to do is to execute every combination of widget and pricing model to determine the outcomes of the pricing across the permutations of the models. The pricing models themselves will examine each widget and determine pricing based on the decision tree within the model.

This makes sense from a parallel processing on commodity infrastructure perspective in my mind but from a technical perspective I do not know if it's possible to execute external models within the MR jobs and from a practical perspective whether or not I am trying to force a use case into the technology.

The question therefore becomes is it possible; does it make sense to implement in this fashion; and if not what are other options / patterns more suited to this scenario?

EDIT
The volume and variety will grow over time.  Assume for the sake of discussion here that we have a terabyte of widgets and 10s of pricing models currently.  We would then expect to gro into multiple terabytes and 100s of pricing models and that the execution of the permutations would would happen frequently as widgets change and/or are added and as new categories of pricing models are introduced.

Comment: Interesting... Can you be more specific about how much data you have? MapReduce, Hadoop and BigData are great, but honestly they are overkill unless you have upwards of Terabytes of raw data to process.

Answer (score 0):

You certainly need a scalable, parallel-izable solution and hadoop can be that.  You just have to massage your solution a bit so it would fit into the hadoop world.

First, You'll need to make the models and widgets implement common interfaces (speaking very abstractly here) so that you can apply and arbitrary model to an arbitrary widget without having to know anything about the actual implementation or representation.

Second, you'll have to be able to reference both models and widgets by id.  That will let you build objects (writables) that hold the id of a model and the id of a widget and would thus represent one "cell" in the cross product of widgets and models.  You distribute these instances across multiple servers and in doing so distribute the application of models to widgets across multiple servers.  These objects (call it class ModelApply) would hold the results of a specific model-to-widget application and can be processed in the usual way with hadoop to repost on best applications.

Third, and this is the tricky part, you need to compute the actual cross product of models to widgets.  You say the number of models (and therefore model id's) will number in at most the hundreds.  This means that you could load that list of id's into memory in a mapper and map that list to widget id's.  Each call to the mapper's map() method would pass in a widget id and would write out one instance of ModelApply for each model.

I'll leave it at that for now.